# How to convert cmis event object id to cmis document object id or vice versa

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I was trying out alfresco with openCMIS and ran into this issue.
When am retrieving id of a CMISObject I'm getting object id like **`workspace://SpacesStore/3a2bcd68-aabc-42ed-8229-bf8237aa59b7;1.0`**. And when am accessing changes in alfresco am getting object id of event as **`3a2bcd68-aabc-42ed-8229-bf8237aa59b7;1.0`**. How do I get rid of ***workspace://SpaceStore*** ?

Code snippets :-

```
private void getAllFilesInPath(String folderId, ArrayList<String> filesList) {
   ItemIterable<CmisObject> children = FileUtils.getFolder(folderId, sessionObject).getChildren();

          for (CmisObject object : children) {
              if (object instanceof Folder) {
               getAllFilesInPath(object.getId(), filesList);
               } else if (object instanceof Document) {
                                filesList.add(object.getId());
              }
            }
         System.out.println(filesList.get(0));
    }
```

Output : **`workspace://SpacesStore/3a2bcd68-aabc-42ed-8229-bf8237aa59b7;1.0`**

```
 ItemIterable<ChangeEvent> events = sessionObject.
                              getContentChanges(currentChangeToken, true);
    for (ChangeEvent changeEvent : events) {
    objectId = changeEvent.getObjectId();
    System.out.println(objectId);
```

Output : **`3a2bcd68-aabc-42ed-8229-bf8237aa59b7;1.0`**

Is there any way to do this.Please help.

Comment: What CMIS Endpoint are you talking to? (I think you might be talking to the wrong one...)

Comment: My atompub_url : http://localhost:6080/alfresco/cmisatom . Is it incorrect ?

Comment: See [here on the Alfresco wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#RESTful_AtomPub_Binding) for the full list, `http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom` or `http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom` are the recommended new-style ones

Comment: When I'm doing that it gets this exception . Anything on this ? Am connecting using repo id.                                                                Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Unknown repository '6b3559f1-e2e1-48e4-87ea-abb3a82db452'!
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:499)

Comment: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Unknown repository '6b3559f1-e2e1-48e4-87ea-abb3a82db452'! at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService‌​.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:499)

Comment: The repository ID might not be in quite the same format between the different endpoints. Make sure you connect with no ID, then get the list of Repository IDs to be sure

Comment: But in my case I need repository id to check for changes support,get latest change token etc.

Comment: Just call [getRepositories](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.14.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/SessionFactory.html#getRepositories-java.util.Map-) the first time to see what's there

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments posted by Gagravarr I came to know that I'm talking to the wrong alfresco endpoint. I've changed my AtomPub URL parameter to

**`http://localhost:6080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom`**

Now it works fine. I used repository id as *`-default-`* obtained by calling ***getRepositories*** method first time.

Reference : 1. [CMIS REST AtomPub URL reference](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#RESTful_AtomPub_Binding)
2.[CMIS Request URL format(On premise)](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/pra/1/concepts/cmis-request-url-format-onpremise.html)

Thanks to Gagravarr :)